# Use a symbol in a formula that's been defined over elsewhere

Tags: amsmath, verbatim

In my document preamble, I'm using:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
```

It means I can indicate that things are to be rendered as code with `|This_is_monospaced|`, but now I'm trying to use vertical bars to represent magnitude in a formula, as such: `$|V|$` (typeset with amsmath)

What I'm currently getting is a verbatim environment within my formula.

Is there a way of temporarily disabling the monospacing behaviour so my formula still renders normally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load `amsmath`

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

and then use

```
$\lvert V\rvert$
```

Another option is to use `\UndefineShortVerb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}

$\lvert V\rvert$

\UndefineShortVerb{\|}
$|V|$
\DefineShortVerb{\|}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Andrew Swann** mentions in his comment, in general it is preferable to use `\lvert...\rvert` instead of just `|...|`.

Comment: and I'm already using amsmath :)

Comment: In fact you should always use `\lvert` and `\rvert` for `|V|` to get correct spacing.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Can you please provide an example showing a difference in spacing using `|...|` and `\lvert...\rvert`? (I've been trying to produce one but haven't found it)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Actually looking this up in the TeX book page 170, there are only two situations where `\lvert` which is class _Open_ and `|` which is class _Ord_ differ in spacing: when they are next to an _Op_, i.e. a large operator.  So `\( \bigoplus \lvert V \rvert \)` has less space than `\( \bigoplus |V| \)`, similarly when the first two terms are swapped. There are more cases when spacing for `\rvert` differs from that for `|`, including the situation where the `V` is replaced by a `\left/\right` pair.  `amsldoc` explains that there are semantic reasons to prefer `\lvert` etc.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you very much for your answer! I'll add some remark to my answer.